# Flex 3: "y" not having any effect on an image

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, coordinates

In one of my children, I have the following code:

```
<mx:Canvas id="projWrapper" x="{parentApplication.oneDay * startOffset}" width="{parentApplication.oneDay * numDays}" height="26" backgroundColor="{conflictBG}" borderColor="#000000" borderSides="bottom top left right" borderStyle="solid" borderThickness="1">
    <mx:HBox verticalGap="0">
        <mx:Image id="expandBlockLeft" source="images/addRed.png" y="5" />
        <mx:Text id="sNameShow" text="{sName}" />
    </mx:HBox>
</mx:Canvas>
```

the image, which is a small plus ("+") sign, is starting at coordinate 0, 0 of the canvas.  I need it to start at 0, 5... however, no matter what I change the y value to, the plus sign doesn't move.

I know this seems simple, and I'm sure it is, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

If anybody can shed some light onto my little issue here, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use:

```
<mx:Canvas id="projWrapper" x="{parentApplication.oneDay * startOffset}" width="{parentApplication.oneDay * numDays}" height="26" backgroundColor="{conflictBG}" borderColor="#000000" borderSides="bottom top left right" borderStyle="solid" borderThickness="1">
    <mx:HBox verticalGap="0" paddingTop="5">
        <mx:Image id="expandBlockLeft" source="images/addRed.png" />
        <mx:Text id="sNameShow" text="{sName}" />
    </mx:HBox>
</mx:Canvas>
```

The problem is `HBox` layout container doesn't support custom precise positioning with `x` and `y` and response for the positioning itself (by design). You can use gaps, paddings and align to have some custom adjustments or use container with absolute positioning like `Canvas`.

Comment: But wouldn't that also move the text element?  The text is showing up where I need it to, just not the image.  I might just remove the HBox, and place things manually.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: If you really want a dynamic layout but want to move your image down without changing the padding, you can do a vbox around the image and add a 5px '<mx:Spacer height="5"/>' above the image.

Comment: If you just want to move the image down 5px, you can wrap it into a new Box and make that Box.paddingTop=5